# Straight line problem : Find the number of points which lies between the figure : $(0,0) , (0,21); (20,0)$

Tags: coordinate-systems, geometric-construction

**Problem:**

> Find the number of points which lies inside the triangle  : $(0,0) , (0,21); (20,0) $

Approach :

Let us take point $A = (0,0)$, $B = (0,21)$, and $C = (20,0)$.

Since the figure formed by joining these points $ABC$ is a triangle where:

Point $A$ lies on origin; $B$ lies on $y$-axis and $C$ lies on $x$-axis. 
I am unable to find the condition to find the number of points which lies in this triangle.

Please help in this context.. thanks...

Comment: I'm assuming that these points should have integer x and y values?

Comment: Yes, is there a condition that the coordinates should have integer values? There are infinitely many points in a line, what more in a plane?

Answer (score 2):

If a point $(x,y)$ is on the origin side of line $BC$, the point satisfies this inequality:
$$\begin{align}
y \le& 21 - \frac{21}{20}x\\
y \le& 21 - x -\frac{x}{20}
\end{align}$$

And the maximum integer $y$ that satisfies this inequality is dependent on $x$, and is given by $\left\lfloor21 - x -\frac{x}{20}\right\rfloor$. For integer $x$, this is equivalent to $21-x-\left\lceil\frac{x}{20}\right\rceil$. The last ceiling is $0$ for $x=0$ and $1$ for $x\in \{1,2,3,\ldots,19\}$.

So if you were to count all integer coordinates inside the triangle, you should sum the maximum integer $y$ over $x\in \{1,2,3,\ldots,19\}$.

$$\begin{align}
S=\sum_{x=1}^{19}{\sum_{y=1}^{\left\lfloor21 - x -\frac{x}{20}\right\rfloor}1}
=&\sum_{x=1}^{19}\left\lfloor21 - x -\frac{x}{20}\right\rfloor\\
=& \sum_{x=1}^{19}\left(21-x-\left\lceil\frac{x}{20}\right\rceil\right)\\
=& \sum_{x=1}^{19}\left(21-x-1\right)\\
=& \sum_{x=1}^{19}\left(20-x\right)\\
\end{align}$$

This should not be too difficult. If you also want the point on the boundary, you can do so similarly.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ a lattice polygon, $A$ it's area, $I$ the number of the interior lattice points, $B$ number the lattice points on the boundary of $P$. Then
$$A=I+B/2-1.$$
This is known as Pick's theorem.  From here we conclude $211=I+B/2$. Obviously there are $42$ points on both axis and no lattice point on the line segment from $(0,21)$ to $(20,0)$: It's slope is $-21/20$, assuming a lattice point on the segment, one could reduce $-21/20$.
So $B/2=21\Rightarrow I=190\Rightarrow I+B=232$.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

### Hint

Take the equations:
$$
\begin{align}
0 \le x & \le 20 \\
0 \le y &\le 21 \\
\dfrac{x}{20} + \dfrac{y}{21} &\le 1 \\
x, \ y \in \left\{0,\ 1,\ 2,\ 3,\ \cdots \right\}
\end{align}
$$